# How to use Atomic counters with Spring Data Couchbase Reactive

Tags: reactive-programming, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using Spring Data couchbase reactive to perform read, write, update operations. Now I have a need for something like Atomic Counters in Couchbase for one of the attributes. I read that Spring reactive doesn't support this ( may it is now) feature yet, so would like guidance about how to go about this.

I have already looked at the solution provided in other ticket: [Atomic counters in Spring with Couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507421/atomic-counters-in-spring-with-couchbase)
But this is not blocking calls, so I was wondering if I can have something similar for making non blocking calls as well.

I can use Couchbase's reactive client for this but then it means I need to combine Reactive client of Couchbase and Spring Data Couchbase reactive for which I am not too confident if it is good approach or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atomic counters are not part of the Spring Data specification (Spring Data was originally designed for RDBMS)

A few options are:

1) Make a simple sync call via the bucket object:

```
myRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().counter("mycounter", 1L, 1L );
```

2) Use the standard Couchbase Java Reactive SDK (RxJava) and convert the Observable:
[Adapting RxJava 1.1.5 to Reactor Core 3.1.0.M3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405837/adapting-rxjava-1-1-5-to-reactor-core-3-1-0-m3)

Comment: so if I select option 2 then I have to all the calls using only Couchbase Java Reactive SDK (RxJava) then?

Comment: You can "mix" both SDKs, so only this place is where you need to use the standard java sdk.

Comment: You can access it via myrepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().async()